# Minecraft Animation: My grass has black texture after render. How Do I Fix?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing

For some reason when i render my scene in Blender my minecraft grass texture has a black background, not all the grass has the black background but most do and it is an annoyance. I just want to know how to fix it. I didn't change any settings, and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere after googling for an hour. There is a video how ever it is using Blender Render, and I am using Cycles. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your light bounces are low for that many transparent images.

Try increasing your transparency light bounces under 
Properties > Render > Light Paths > Max Bounces > Transparency